# What can I do I to loosen up my outboard steering?

Tags: boats, outboard-engine

The steering on my Yamaha 50TLR outboard motor is very stiff.

What can I do to make it easier to steer?

Comment: Would need to know a little more about what kind of boat you have.  No all setups are the same.

Comment: I added my specific motor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Russell's comment is very valid, however the first things to look at in any case:

- If the outboard is moved by cable from a steering wheel, check every cable guide and the bearings in the steering wheel. All should be lubricated, without rust and freely moving.
- The bearings on the outboard pivot should also be lubricated and freely moving

All those should be easy to check individually.